# Interaction between custom Java code and Python code in Spark

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

We've got Java libraries for doing certain things (querying the backend intelligently, mostly) in a Spark environment.  I'd like to use their functionality but develop in Python.  Is there a standard way of doing this (`this' probably meaning: passing RDDs and the active SparkContext between Java and Python)?

I've [seen](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/PySpark+Internals) that PySpark uses [Py4J](https://www.py4j.org/) to expose the SparkContext, so I guess I can more or less run all the Java code I want from Python.  However, looking at the Python wrappers of the Py4J interface, it looks like there's a lot go get wrong and a more throd-out path would seem preferable.

Comment: Since PySpark also uses Py4J to communicate with Java, Py4J is good to start with. You can add some of your sample code here in case you are facing any issues.